# Theming node add form

Tags: theming

I have a content type 'project' and I want to theme the node add form for this content type, I tried to create a page--node--add-project.tpl.php but I don't have the list of form element to render in this file.
devel_themer don't print the variables list in the node add page
thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I'm pretty sure that's not going to work. Here's a good overview/discussion on theming node forms: https://www.drupal.org/node/1092122

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code in your template.php

```
/**
* Implements hook_theme().
*/
function mytheme_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return array(
        'project_node_form' => array(
        'render element' => 'form',
        'template' => 'project-node-form',
       // this will set to module/theme path by default:
       'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/templates',
     ),
  );
}
```

Place project-node-form.tpl.php in your themes templates directory.

Answer (score 0):

On the page level forms are rendered and so you cannot get its elements. You will need to implement a hook_theme function in template.php file where you define the path of the template file and also implement preprocess function if required.

You can see a detailed explaination here .. [Theming Forms with Template file](http://themery.com/dgd7/advanced-theming/forms/with-templates)